# What sensors can measure 3-axis acceleration?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm currently measuring vibration, temp and noise using an Arduino and various inexpensive sensors. The acceleration sensor i found was sensors that measured the gravity on 3-axis of the sensor. But i'd like to measure acc, not gravity, as it moves in the direction of the sensor. For example, if an object is moving front-dir in a horizontal location, the x-directional acc is measured.

Could you tell me if you know the acc soensor i want.

Comment: 3-axis accelerometer. And yes, they measure gravity. After all, gravity is just acceleration downwards (9.8m/s²)...

Answer (score 1):

> The acceleration sensor i found was sensors that measured the gravity on 3-axis of the sensor

Gravity *is* acceleration.

An accelerometer measures acceleration - or more accurately, it senses the resistance to acceleration (inertia) and equates that to acceleration.

By holding an accelerometer still you are causing it to resist the pull of gravity, and it's that "resistance" that it measures - a constant 9.8m/s²

If you let the accelerometer freefall it won't be resisting gravity any more, and will measure 0 for the Z axis.

So you simply have to "ignore" gravity, by removing that constant 9.8m/s² ("1g") of acceleration from the Z axis.  And you do that by simply subtracting it.

It is normal to calibrate an accelerometer by keeping it at rest and reading the "idle" values. Those values are then subtracted from the readings to give you the actual value.

Comment: But, I want to check x and y-dir accs, not gravity. (front(x-dir) acc, on planar)

Comment: Yes? And? that's what the other two axes are for. X (forwards/backwards), Y (sideways) and Z (up/down+gravity).

Comment: Does this mean that these acceleration measurements are also possible?; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38962719/how-to-get-acceleration-and-deceleration-like-a-car-in-android   I didn't get the desired value when I moved the acceleration sensor in plane. I used the MPU6050.

Comment: Then either you are doing something wrong in your code, or you fundamentally misunderstand the basic nature of the universe.

Comment: https://physics.info/kinematics-calculus/

Comment: How to remove gravity from axis-acceleration? I'd searched this but i was able to find that i want. Could you tell me the code I want ?

Comment: `z = z - 9.8;` -- assuming Z is vertical acceleration in g.

Comment: yes. i have already done. but if the x-axis is oriented upwards, 9.8 is detected.

Comment: Then what you want to do is convert the three individual axes into a 3D vector, then subtract the 3D vector of the sensor when stationary.

Comment: Oh, the way you're talking about it, first get the roll, pitch, and yaw using the gyro, and then use it to make a three-dimensional transformation. Is it right that i understand?

Comment: There is a library, IIRC, that takes all 6 values and does some fancy maths with them to give you useful values. I have never used it and don't know what it's called, but maybe Google could find it for you. It sounds like that is what you need.

Comment: acceleration is not gravity. something sitting on the table, z axis of the sensor upward, should have 0 accel, not 9.81 m/s/s. In freefall it is accelerating at g, not 0. It is easy enough to subtract out 9.81 from that reading but that does not work when the orientation of the sensor will vary in use (and integrating orientation over time does not provide the accuracy needed). what I really want is a sensor that actually reads acceleration!!

Comment: @JonathanWeaver https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle